# Pydantic AttributeError: '' object has no attribute '__fields_set__'

Tags: python, class, inheritance, pydantic

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class A(BaseModel):
    date = ''

class B(A):
    person: float

    def __init__(self):
        self.person = 0
    
B()
```

tried to initiate class B but raised error AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '**fields_set**', why is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you override the `__init__` and do not call `super` there so Pydantic cannot do it's magic with setting proper fields.

With pydantic it's rare you need to implement your `__init__` most cases can be solved different way:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class A(BaseModel):
    date = ""

class B(A):
    person: float = 0

B()
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I make a new constructor if I want to initiate class B with extra parameters?

Comment: What are the extra parameters? Why don't you put them below the `person` parameter?

Comment: nevermind, I see what you mean now. Thank you.

Comment: You can use a root validator https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/  to validate, and modify, field values.  Somewhat akin to dataclass postinits.   Doesnt take params.